# Start ArcGIS Web Map Zoomed to Query

Tags: arcgis-online, extents, query, html

Can you have an ArcGIS Online map, *you know one that you share and embed on a web page or link to*, automatically start at an extent that is defined in a query of some sort?

Ideally it would be great if it could be inserted into the HTML link such as:

https://domain.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=a618e74cc2cb439197413549eeb1256bx123&**Fieldname=XYZ**

Can this be accomplished or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure feature search for that layer on the field you wish to be searchable. Once you have done that use the &find=XYZ which will return that result.

You configure feature search on the web map settings tab on the item details page for the web map. The layer must have query enabled to work.

Comment: That is super friggen helpful. Thank you good sir.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding this info as I'm still new to AGOL. Where do I find "the web map settings tab on the item details page for the web map. The layer must have query enabled to work." The only settings I see on the item details page for my web map are: Content Status, Delete Protection, Extent, Save As, Layer Settings, and Application Settings (Find Locations and Use in ArcGIS Field Maps). The Find Locations option excludes several of my data fields, including the one I want to be able to search (ID). I'm not seeing where to enable queries on the feature layer itself. Thank you!

Comment: @coelacanth this is in the application you are configuring. When you open the app to configure (well this depends on the app) but there is generally a search tab in options. In there you can select the layer(s) you'd like to be able to search and the default source (which is what would work with the above).

Comment: @CodyBrown Hm, shoot. I must just be looking at something completely different (but thank you for trying to help)! Opening the "Web Appbuilder", I see tabs for Theme, Map, Widget, and Attribute. The Map tab allows me to select which Web Map to display. Nothing called "Options" or a search tab.