# Linking to a specific point in an arcgis online map

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a map in arcgis online with point data. Each of these points shows houses that have been destroyed by time. We have a wiki that tells the history about these houses, so I was wondering if there is a way to either link to the points location in the map (so I could just drop the link in the wiki), or extract a png file of an extent around the point and show that image in the wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you check out this post linked below
[Start ArcGIS Web Map Zoomed to Query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297570/start-arcgis-web-map-zoomed-to-query)

pretty much configure feature search in your web map for the points probably using the address field and then generate a url for that field with that address and use that url as the link in the wiki.